# Different classes of the same type with the same observer, how to do?

Tags: java, static, observers

So I create a class X, which has static variables, in my main function. I also add an observer to class X. 
When I create a new instance of class X in a different class my observers don't get notified anymore, because it is a different class instance of class X. How do I manage to notify my observers anyway, without having to pass that class X through my whole program which is pretty impossible?
The problem is that the newly created instances of ClassX don't have an observer attached.

```
/*different file*/
public class CreatingNewX{
    public void incrementSomeValue1(){
        ClassX x = new ClassX();
        x.someMethod();
    }
}

/*different file*/
public class observer implements Observer {
    private ClassX ClassXValue = null;

    public observer(ClassX ClassXValue){
        this.ClassXValue = ClassXValue;
    }

    public void update(Observable obs, Object obj){
        if(obs == ClassXValue){
            /*do something*/
        }
    }

}

/*different file*/
public class ClassX extends Observable {
    private static int somevalue1;
    private static int somevalue2;
    private static int somevalue3;

    public void someMethod(){
        somevalue1++;
        setChanged(); 
        notifyObservers(); 
    }

}

/*different file*/
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassX X = new ClassX();
        ClassObserver observer = new ClassObserver(X);
        X.addObserver(observer);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please read [MCVE] and edit your question.

Comment: Added an example, but in reality it is larger and more complicated than this example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I believe you are looking for a way to check if an Observable object passed into your `update` method is an instance of type `ClassX`. You should use the `instanceof` operator, which returns true if the given object is an instance of the given class type and false if the object is null or not of that class type.

```
public void update(Observable obs, Object obj){
        if(obs instanceof ClassX){
            /*do something*/ // this will only execute if 'obs' is of type ClassX
        }
    }
```

More on instanceof: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html (towards the bottom).

Comment: But since I am creating a new instance of ClassX, and only the instance of the class in the main method has observers attached, it won't work.

Comment: I'll admit I'm still a little unclear as to what your problem is. Could you clarify? Why do you need a new instance of ClassX elsewhere?

Comment: I want to repaint() in the update() method. I need a different class because it is an action which has to use ClassX. Even if I add observers to the action it won't work, only when resizing.I managed to do it with a update every x milliseconds, but you are not allowed to do it like that according to the assignment.

Comment: I managed to do it by adding observer as a static type to ClassX. It is probably a very ugly solution, but it works :D